# space of vectors perpendicular to plane in R^3

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Is space of vectors perpendicular to any plane in R^3 always one-dimensional?
In other words, do two planes never be perpendicular in R^3 space?

Comment: Correct. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Yes to the first question. No to the second. Given a plane $\mathbb{P}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set of all multiples of its normal vector is the space of vectors perpendicular to it. But if the normal vector $\mathbf{n_1}$  of plane  $\mathbb{P_1}$ is orthogonal to the normal vector $\mathbf{n_2}$  of plane  $\mathbb{P_2}$ then the two planes are perpendicular to each other. For example, the $xy$ plane is perpendicular to the $yz$ plane and both are perpendicular to the $xz$ plane.

Comment: Well, there are no orthogonal 2D subspaces of R^3 would be the correct way to say what you want. Apparently planes in 3D space being perpendicular is a relaxed condition.